# table for organizing students registration of subjects

Tags: python, database, algorithm, data-structures

I have to create my own subjects table, I have an excel file which contain subjects groups and dates that are available, I want to create a python program to run over all the combinations of subjects to give me all the available dates of subjects which I want to register in .
actually, I have no idea even how to start,
now I have four subjects let's call them F,N,S and G. 
each one has four groups with different times along the week 
so I want to generate all the available combinations which there is no overlap between subjects .
all I want is any hint, I don't want the whole solution just any intial thoughts to start. 
I'm really a beginner python programmer and I can't think of any thing to launch this project

how to arrange them into matrices????????

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the excel file as a `csv`, or "comma-separated values" file. This format is simple plaintext, and easy for programs to use.
2. In your program, read in the file using `open()`
3. Use the `csv` module to extract the opened file into a list of lists. Each element of the outer list should be another list: `[subject, group, date]` (or whatever columns are in your table.
4. Now that you have your information read into the program, look into solutions for the actual algorithm. You can google various scheduling algorithms, but [this StackOverflow question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330885/job-scheduling-algorithm-to-find-the-maximum-number-of-overlapping-jobs) gets at what you're looking for, I think, and might serve as a good starting point

Comment: could you just take look on the excel file to just be informed with how the data organized because I 'm not sure I follow you!

Comment: You did not include the excel function in your question, so I cannot

Comment: please take a look and guide me just to start it